# Making the following code work for responsive capabilities

Tags: jquery, css

I have this following code to make the top nav bar disappear, the question I'm asking is that how would I go about making it only work in widths of under 680 pixels? Apart from that it works totally fine.

```
var mywindow = $(window);
        var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
        var up = false;
        var newscroll;
        mywindow.scroll(function () {
            newscroll = mywindow.scrollTop();
            if (newscroll > mypos && !up) {
                $('header').fadeOut();
                up = !up;
                console.log(up);
            } else if(newscroll < mypos && up) {
                $('header').fadeIn();
                up = !up;
            }
            mypos = newscroll;
        });
```

FIXED. Mostly. The Script will still stop / start working when the width is passed by resizing the window. Not sure how to stop this.

//remove navbar on lower width pages

```
   function toggleBar(){
        var mywindow = $(window);
        var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
        var up = false;
        var newscroll;

        mywindow.scroll(function () {
            newscroll = mywindow.scrollTop();
            if (newscroll > mypos && !up) {
                $('header').stop().fadeOut();
                up = !up;
                console.log(up);
            } else if(newscroll < mypos && up) {
                $('header').stop().fadeIn();
                up = !up;
            }
            mypos = newscroll;
            });
        }

//REMOVE NAVBAR (place this in document load)
        $(window).load(function() {
          var pageWidth = $(window).width(); 
                    if (pageWidth < 640){
                        toggleBar();
                        $('header').attr('href','../../../css/main.css');                  
                    }      

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var windowsize = $window.width();
   if (windowsize < 680 ) {

    var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
    var up = false;
    var newscroll;
    mywindow.scroll(function () {
        newscroll = mywindow.scrollTop();
        if (newscroll > mypos && !up) {
            $('header').fadeOut();
            up = !up;
            console.log(up);
        } else if(newscroll < mypos && up) {
            $('header').fadeIn();
            up = !up;
        }
        mypos = newscroll;
    });

  }
```

Comment: Hi, that doesn't work unfortunately, the logic does seem sound though so I'm not sure why it doesn't work!

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Are there any errors or anything? Maybe you could set up a fiddle with a sample code so we could try to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: the console brought up errors. I've got it working (mostly, the script will still turn on / off if the pixel width is passed by resizing the window). I will post the edit in the question.

Comment: Jquery has a window.onresize function that you could use: window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};

Comment: That was what I was using to try and force it to work, it wasn't until I changed my code to what it is until it worked. I have no idea why onresize didn't work!